# Como posso criar um visual de Cartela de Apostas de 20 números no Jframe

Tags: java, jframe, qtgui

É um jogo onde sua aposta estará concorrendo a Sena, Quina e Quadra, por isso cada aposta só pode ter 6 números, eu preciso que usuário selecione 6 números dentre esses 20 e depois eu pego esses 6 selecionados e faço a aposta dele. Mas eu só preciso dessa **Cartela de Apostas**.

Então Como posso criar uma **Cartela de Apostas** de 20 números onde você selecionará apenas 6 deles clicando nele, depois pegar os números que foram selecionados. 
A parte de comparação e criar números randomicamente já está pronta e funcionando, eu estou usando 6 ***JComboBox*** de 1 a 20 para que o usuário escolha os 6 números, mas seria mais prático se ele clicasse nos números espalhados na tela, eu também queria uma bola atrás de cada número pra dar uma ideia de Bingo.
Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: É um jogo onde sua aposta estará concorrendo a Sena, Quina e Quadra, por isso cada aposta só pode ter 6 números, eu preciso que usuário selecione 6 números dentre esses 20 e depois eu pego esses 6 selecionados e faço a aposta dele.

Comment: Ok vou preparar uma resposta para ver se te ajuda, contudo havias de reformular a tua pergunta está um pouco confusa

Comment: ok obrigado, farei isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifica o código, penso que assim fica mais pratico do que selecionar os números por uma `combobox`, falta implementar a regra de só deixar selecionar 5 números, mas isso penso que agora consigas fazer.

*Código:*

```
public class Matrizz extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private List<JToggleButton> listTogglebu = new ArrayList<JToggleButton>(20);
/**
 * Creates new form Matrizz
 */
public Matrizz() {
    initComponents();
    JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
    jPanel1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    this.setSize(500,300);
    this.add(jPanel1);
    this.add(jPanel2);
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 10));



    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        listTogglebu.add(new JToggleButton("" + (y + 1)));
        jPanel1.add(listTogglebu.get(y));
    }
    JButton ver = new JButton("Selecionados");

    jPanel2.add(ver);
     ver.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      printSelecionado();
                 }


        });


}
  private void printSelecionado() {
            for (JToggleButton jToggleButton : listTogglebu) {
                if(jToggleButton.isSelected())System.out.println(" numero:"+jToggleButton.getText());

      }
        }
```

*resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*output:*

```
run:  
numero:3
numero:4
numero:6
numero:12 
numero:15
numero:17
```

Comment: Ficou legal J Santos, eu irei implementar desse jeito mesmo, ficou mais prático, era exatamente isso que eu queria, Obrigado!